# Requirements for content widget which reveals only when triggered by mouse click. Troubled on requirements of JS or if CSS can perform this

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am building a module for a website that displays mostly text information for different subjects and categories, and within each module will be a function that, when triggered by mouse click, reveals a citation/source reference collection for the subject. I have located an existing service, known as graphiq.com, that is very very close to what I am building. I am presenting graphiq's embeddable data module as an example.

Their embedabble module contains a subject (in my example, an Orca) and presents primarily descriptive text about the animal.

The function that I am specifically asking for help on is the "Show Details" element contained in the lower portion of the module. It is a clickable link that when triggered by mouse, reveals with a brief animation a new portion of text that contains the references to sources, and other additional text information relevant for citation and source confirmation.

Here is a before and after screenshot of the graphiq.com module.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWbeS.jpg

And here is the actual module.

https://www.graphiq.com/vlp/k0i6yt5ld9X

My diligence so far informs me that for certain there is CSS class named `dsrc dsrc-expand-overlay` that has the following transform code

```
.dsrc-expand-overlay {
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .35s ease;
transition: -webkit-transform .35s ease;
transition: transform .35s ease;
transition: transform .35s ease,-webkit-transform .35s ease;
transition-property: transform, -webkit-transform;
transition-duration: 0.35s, 0.35s;
transition-timing-function: ease, ease;
transition-delay: initial, initial;
background-color: white;
-webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
-ms-transform: translateY(0%);
transform: translateY(0%);
border-top: 1px #e1e1e1 solid;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: 550;
position: absolute;
display: block;
}
```

However, I believe it is also calling upon JavaScript as when I inspect the Event Listener Breakpoints in Chrome Dev Tools, and I click that "Show Details" text, I am informed of the jquery.min.js file firing at the line that contains this instruction:

```
  return function() {
     b && (delete Dc[g],
     b = f.onload = f.onerror = null,
     "abort" === a ? f.abort() : "error" === a ? d(f.status, f.statusText) : 
     d(Ec[f.status] || f.status, f.statusText, "string" == typeof 
     f.responseText? {
     text: f.responseText } : void 0, f.getAllResponseHeaders()))
       }
     }
```

I have been unable to reproduce the animated reveal effect in my own experiments using that CSS code, and am stuck as I am very new to JavaScript which means I may be mis-diagnosing the failure to not capturing this functions proper JavaScript in its entirety.

I have created a JSFiddle with the graphiq.com orca module that I just pulled code using Chrome Dev Tools, that is broken, to share for further clarity.

http://jsfiddle.net/apsfgcz0/

Comment: So what you are basically asking more or less boils down to, _“how do I reveal hidden content with JavaScript, starting from the bottom”_ …?

Comment: CBroe, that is mostly correct, but it would be ideal if I could imitate my examples reveal function using only CSS.

The user should be able to reveal hidden content upon mouse click, as well as re-hide that content if/when they are ready to return to the primary text content.

Comment: Well if you want to trigger different formatting depending on an element being “clicked”, that usually means using either `:target` or `:check` pseudo classes (the latter in combination with a hidden checkbox and label as trigger elements.)